# Silverlight: How can I update an IValueConverter bound Textbox upon changing values in an Entity?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, datagrid, ria, ivalueconverter

So, I have a DataGrid with a TextBlock that displays the aggregrate value of two textboxes in the grid. I do this by binding using a value converter. This works on the load but I need it to update upon changing the values of the other entities which its aggregating over.  Here is some of my code:

Here is the my PagedCollectionView in my ViewModel which is bound to the View.

```
private PagedCollectionView _grievances;
public PagedCollectionView Grievances
{
    get
    {
        if (_grievances == null)
        {
            _grievances = new PagedCollectionView(Context.lict_grievances);
            _grievances.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("grievance_type_id", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        }

        return _grievances;
    }
}
```

Here is my the DataGrid in my View:

```
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="grdGrievances" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Grievances}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>

        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Total # of Outcomes">
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource GrievanceOutcomeSum}}" Margin="15,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Resolved">
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=outcome_resolved, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                             TextChanged="ResolvedTextBox_TextChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>


        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Pending">
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=outcome_pending, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>

    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

Here is my Value Converter for the aggregated textblock:

```
public class GrievancesAggregateConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        lict_grievance entity = (lict_grievance)value;
        short i = 0;

        if (entity != null)
        {
            if (entity.outcome_resolved != null)
                i += (short)entity.outcome_resolved;

            if (entity.outcome_pending != null)
                i += (short)entity.outcome_pending;
        }
        return i;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

So, upon changing the values in the other 2 textboxes I need it to refresh the aggregrated value in the textblock.  How can I accomplish this? Im at a loss right now and browsing the web I couldnt find any solutions.

Thanks a bunch,
Evan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evan, Colin Eberhardt has an interesting so called ["MultiBinding" solution](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/05/silverlight-multibinding-solution-for-silverlight-4/) on his blog and is doing something very similar.

> "MultiBinding is a WPF feature that
>   allows you to bind a single property
>   to a number of sources, with the
>   source values being combined by a
>   value converter. This is a feature
>   that is missing from Silverlight"
>   (Quote)

This should solve your problem. Best regards!

Comment: Check this out also, apparently Colin's solution had some leaks, I don't know if they still do. http://blog.thekieners.com/2010/09/08/relativesource-binding-with-findancestor-mode-in-silverlight/

Comment: Yeah Derek, thanks. You might also check if you have the new Silverlight 4 GDR release "4.0.60129.0" which resolves a "A memory leak occurs if a Silverlight 4 application has an inline data template in a control" ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2495644/en-us )

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you bind the TextBlock (Total # of Outcomes) to a property that will fire PropertyChanged.  Then set that value from the ResolvedTextBox_TextChanged event.

Try something like this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ei:PropertyChangedTrigger Binding="{Binding FirstTextBox}">
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=textBlock}"
                                     PropertyName="Text"
                                     Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TestConverter}}" />
        </ei:PropertyChangedTrigger>
        <ei:PropertyChangedTrigger Binding="{Binding SecondTextBox}">
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=textBlock}"
                                     PropertyName="Text"
                                     Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TestConverter}}" />
        </ei:PropertyChangedTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" />
    <TextBox x:Name="firstTextBox"
             Text="{Binding FirstTextBox, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <TextBox x:Name="secondTextBox"
             Text="{Binding SecondTextBox, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Because the Entities are coming from RIA Services and are Generated Entities from Entity Framework. So, I dont think I can edit the Entity Object and put a Totals Property in there.

Comment: Could you please provide some code? I'm not sure how I would go about doing that..

Comment: I realize that's not a DataGrid, I can try that as well if that example doesn't help.

Comment: Evan, please not that - in case you don't know - this nice solution requires the "Expression Blend 4 SDK for Silverlight" (or installed Blend) components. Then you will be able to resolve the "System.Windows.Interactivity" and "Microsoft.Expression.Interactions" namespaces.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and this works great if I could get a reference to the control. I can give a name to the textblock in the gridview but how do I get the Behavior to find that control which is in the same row?

Answer (score 0):

try calling  OnApplyTemplate
eg.   grid.OnApplyTemplate()